# How Can I reliablly Arping a Mobile device on LAN

Tags: ping

I am trying detect the presence of devices on a LAN.

I am using the Arping command as follows:

statuscheckIP=os.execute("arping -c 3 -w 5 " .. IP)

However I am getting an occasional false positive. I am only trying to detect the trigger event going from not connected to connected.

Is there a better use of Arping extensions to make the ping check more reliable.  Perhaps only returning true after X amount of true responses in a row?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem (getting false positives) from the command line?

Comment: I have tried that but haven't reproduced the problem. I run the above code every 10sec, but only get a false positive about two to three times an hour.